# Modal interferindo na rolagem da página

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou tendo um problema com modal, pois tenho um modal com vários links e por ter vários links ele cria uma rolagem na página, até ai é normal. Quando clica em um desses links ele abre um outro `modal` que contém uma imagem, acontece que essa imagem também é grande e cria uma rolagem, até ai tudo bem também.

O problema é que quando fecho esse modal com imagem ele deveria manter a rolagem do modal com links, só que não, a rolagem some e não consigo descer mais para ver os outros links.

O site é http://www.escolatarsiladoamaral.com.br no menu **Restrito 1** depois **Cardápios**

Comment: Está utilizando bootstrap?

Comment: @Vinícius Sim, bootstrap.